# std::bad_alloc errors when working with two rasters - want to combine them & analyse the data

Tags: r, dataframe, raster, bad-alloc

I have two rasters: forest class; and fire frequency. They are of the same study area. I want to combine them into a data frame so I can run data analyses.
I have been able to combine them with:

```
class_data <- c(class, data)
```

but converting to a data frame:

```
class_data_df <- as.data.frame(class_data)
```

derives *Error: std::bad_alloc* and so does

```
class_df <- as.data.frame(class)
```

and vice versa.

I have cleared the R unused memory and tried processing on computers with greater capacities but neither has worked.

Does anyone know where I am going wrong, or how I can get around this issue?